# Renderizar dos listas por comas en un elemnto de bootstrap por js

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap

no sé que tan anticuado es esto ... o que me recomienden hacer al respecto, pero tengo dos listas separadas por comas

> 122,1,3,1,1,2,2,1

y

> EMPLEADOS,ANALISTA DE CUENTAS POR PAGAR,AYUDANTE GENERAL,BECARIO,DESARROLLADOR BI,DIRECTOR,DIRECTOR COMERCIAL,DIRECTOR

Necesito meter ambas en un solo **List Group** de bootstrap, no se si es más conveniente convertirlo en un json o algo así para que funcione mejor ... ?

```js
function RenderizarT_A(lb, d) {

   var table = $("#renderizando");
                    $.each(lb, function (rowIndex, r) {
                        var row = $("<li class='list- group - item'>");

                        var campoA = lb[rowIndex];


                        row.append($("</li>" + campoA));


                        table.append(row);
                    });

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>List Group With Badges</h2>
  <ul class="list-group" id="renderizando">

  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la lista de número representa los values de la segunta lista?

Comment: así es mi buen @joalquipe

Comment: a tu elemento li agregale el atributo value y utiliza el rowIndex para acceder a la posición de la otra lista. Siempre y cuando coincida el orden entre las dos listas. Idealmente tu información la deberías obtener estructurada de la forma que necesitas,  es decir, algo como esto [{nombre: "a", id: 1}, {nombre: "b", id: 2}, {nombre: "c", id: 3},]

Comment: bueno podrías darme un ejemplo , yo sé pero para esta ocación me están pasando esas cadenas de esa manera :S

Comment: Donde tienes esto  var row = $("<li class='list- group - item'>"); concatena el value con lista_ids[rowIndex]

Comment: ya he editado y hehco algunos cambios pero no puedo ver su valor solo imprime el **li**

Comment: A que te refieres con solo imprime el li? solamente te sale la lista con los nombres de la segunda lista?. Actualiza tu pregunta con los cambios que hiciste en el código

Comment: ya actualizé los cambios,subí una imagen para mostrarte como se ve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
var table = $("#renderizando");

$.each(l2, function(rowIndex, ele){

  var row = "<li class='list-group-item' value= "+l1[rowIndex]+"> "+ele+" </li>";

  table.append(row);

});
```

Donde l2 es la lista de nombres y l1 la lista con los Ids.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda :3

Comment: No hay problema, hoy por ti mañana por mi :-)